# How do I find the install directory of a Windows Service, using C#?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I'm pretty sure that a Windows service gets C:\winnt (or similar) as its working directory when installed using InstallUtil.exe.  Is there any way I can access, or otherwise capture (at install time), the directory from which the service was originally installed?  At the moment I'm manually entering that into the app.exe.config file, but that's horribly manual and feels like a hack.

Is there a programmatic way, either at run time or install time, to determine where the service was installed from?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the location of the executing assembly. Here's a simple routine that sets the working directory to the location of the executing assembly using reflection:

```
String path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path);
```

Comment: Doesn't this give `C:\Windows\system32`?

Comment: @ProfK, no, it gives the location of the executing assembly.  This would be the directory of the actual executable for the program being run.

Comment: My bad. I found my service looking for app.config in `C:\Windows\system32` and assumed it thought its Location was there.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean you want the directory containing the assembly? If so, that's easy: use [`Assembly.Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx).

I wouldn't try to *change* the working directory of the process though - I wouldn't be surprised if that had nasty side effects, if indeed you're allowed to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Jon.  You were right, the question was not worded quite correctly, so I've changed it.

Comment: So Jon, has this been confirmed that one would NOT want to change the working folder of a service once it's install and/or running, or is there a way to get the working folder set during the Service INSTALL, so that you are able to access files/folders using relative paths, rather than absolute paths?  I'm seeing the same thing with my service, which was written pretty much as an exe for testing/debugging, then defining a single symbol and compiling compiles it to a service, but it's always running out of %SYSTEMROOT%\System32...

Comment: @LarryF: I don't know of any way to change the working directory used for a service, no. That doesn't mean there's no way of doing so, but I don't know of one.

Answer (score 5):

I did not know the `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory` method. Usually I do:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Answer (score 4):

Though very late, but it may help somebody. I solved this issue by using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

```
string someFilePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Resources\SomeResource.xml";
```

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory gave the directory where the windows service was actually isntalled, not the C:\Windows\system32\ path.

I saw it later that @Ramon has already posted the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

`InstallUtil.exe` calls `ServiceInstaller.Install()` of your application at install time.

Override it, add it to the list of your project's `Installers` and get any information you need.

Comment: Thanks.  The runtime approaches of Jon and Steve are actually a better fit for what I need to do.