# How to read a text file from a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have made a Windows Service that gets installed in a `c:\Program Files\My Service` directory. Along with the executable, I have an XML file that gets installed in the same directory. This XML file is used by the service to get user defined information.

In the code of the service I read the file as if it were local to the executable.. example:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("Foo.xml");
```

However, when I run the service, the service throws an exception saying:

> Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\Foo.xml'

Since the executable lives in `c:\Program Files\My Service` I expected the Windows Service to look for the XML file in `c:\Program Files\My Service\Foo.xml`. Obviously, that's not the case.

How can I force the service to look (relatively) for the Foo.xml file in the same location where the service executable lives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the install directory of a Windows Service, using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491735/how-do-i-find-the-install-directory-of-a-windows-service-using-c)

Comment: Just a consideration, you *should not* store configurable application settings in the program files directory as access to modify this path requires privilege. Instead consider using `ApplicationData`/`LocalApplicationData`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Foo.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you what you need

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.ReadXml(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,"Foo.xml");
```

Comment: ... except you don't want to hard-code a path the user can change on installation.

Comment: I want to avoid hard-coding the path to the file. I want the reference to the file to be relative to the executable.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work, because it returns the full path of the assembly including the actual assembly file name itself. You'd need to remove that before this approach would work.

Answer (score 0):

As windows service working directory is C:\Windows\System32.

In order to read your xml file as expected, you have to do as below

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
ds.ReadXml(Path.Combine(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "Foo.xml"));
```